# Hardware upgrades/reconfiguration on Openstack nodes deployed with autopilot

Tags: maas, openstack, cloud, openstack-autopilot

I have a openstack deployed with autopilot. Now I need to do some hardware upgrades on one of my nodes(add RAM and HD). How can/should I do that, since recomissining the node would wipe it clean?